# Aurelia injecting ValidationConfig throws error

Tags: aurelia

```
 import {Router, RouterConfiguration} from 'aurelia-router'
 import {I18N} from 'aurelia-i18n';
 import {autoinject} from 'aurelia-framework';
 import { ValidationConfig } from 'aurelia-validation';


 @autoinject
 export class App {

 router: Router;
 i18n: I18N;

 constructor(i18n: I18N,validationConfig:ValidationConfig) {
    this.i18n = i18n;
 }
```

does not work.
I get a :

> aurelia-pal.js:38 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error invoking undefined. Check > the inner error for details.
>
> Inner Error:
>   Message: Type is not a constructor
>   Inner Error Stack:
>   TypeError: Type is not a constructor
>   at Object.invoke (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:323:14)
>   at InvocationHandler.invoke (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:300:168)
>   at Container.invoke (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:564:25)
>   at StrategyResolver.get (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:127:37)
>   at Container.get (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:501:23)
>   at Object.invoke (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:335:57)
>   at InvocationHandler.invoke (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:300:168)
>   at Container.invoke (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:564:25)
>   at StrategyResolver.get (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:127:37)
>   at Container.get (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:501:23)

If I remove the dependency on ValidationConfig I get no errors.

I am using I18n and want to set the validation's local when the global locale changes.

The plugin is init as follows:

```
.plugin('aurelia-validation', (config:ValidationConfig) => {
  config
    .useLocale('en-US')
    .useViewStrategy((<any>TWBootstrapViewStrategy).AppendToInput);        
})
```

I'm using:
"aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1"
"aurelia-validation": "npm:aurelia-validation@0.6.8"

Answer (score 0):

ValidationConfig has been removed and hence this error is resolved.

> [ValidationConfig no longer exists](https://github.com/aurelia/validation/issues/241#issuecomment-226376433)

The issue was raised on [github by user dstroyrofworlds](https://github.com/aurelia/validation/issues/241).